# Command prompt write a command

Tags: scripting, variable, hostname

its asks me to

> Store the output of the command “hostname” in a variable. Display “This script is running on _.” where “_” is the output of the “hostname” command.

how can I do that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax for storing the output of a command as a variable in GNU/Linux is:

`variable=$(command [option…] argument1 arguments2 …)`

The canonical command for retrieving a node's **hostname** is... (*anyone? anyone?*) `hostname`

Combining that information, assign the output of the `hostname` command to the variable `node`:

`node=$(hostname --fqdn)`

Why not try that, and then see if you can use `printf` to render your variable to a display in combination with the rest of your desired output? If you get stuck try doing: `man printf`.